# When I upload a file on browser, will the server know my file path or disk info?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, file-upload

I believe server can know my file name.

What other info will browser tell the server? File path? Disk info?

Comment: [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav) might help, too.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not. The only thing the server will receive is the raw contents of the file itself and the name of the file. It will not get any other information such as path or file metadata (creation date, etc).

Comment: I think you should add security concerns to your answer.

Comment: @kelalaka I'm under the impression that OP is asking for reasons of privacy, e.g. to avoid revealing things like his name to the server as the name is usually part of the path.

Comment: yes, Your impression is correct. Secure your privacy.